# Android: Reproduce default loading circle in ListFragment

Tags: android, android-listfragment

I noticed that `ListFragments` show the default animated loading circle (indeterminate progressbar) before its adapter is populated with data from a source.

How can I reproduce this behavior on demand? For example: when my adapter is cleared (after it got filled) I want to show this animated circle once more until the adapter is filled again. I tried looking through the documentation but for some reason I can't seem to find how to do it...

Note: I am using `SherlockListFragment`

Comment: have you tried `setListShown(false)`; When your list is empty?

Comment: Well...that was easy. Thanks.